# How model a dimension with composite key?

Tags: data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling

I have a fact named `sales` which have FKs to dimensions `product` and `store`. Each of these dimensions have information about that dimension alone, but I have some information about a `product` in a specific `store` like where a product is in that store.

I am tempted to model a dimension where the primary key is a combination of product and store, it is ok to do that or some better alternative exists?

Comment: The PK for a dimension should always be a surrogate key, not one or more business keys

Comment: This can be answered only by you (and your data). Basically data warehouse can accept some level of de-normalization - which you are introducing. So the point is, if you have much more attributes belonging to the single dimensions and only few one that are dependent on the combination of the dimension - *this will be probably not a good idea*. In the oposit case with few single dimensional attribute and a lot of properties defined for the combination of product and store *simple go this way*.

Comment: "PK for a dimension should always be a surrogate key"  this is often referenced in Powerpoint presentations @NickW , but there are 1) some exceptions: You'll never use surrogates for a time dimension (or any other ordered dimension) if you care for performance. 2) Surrogate keys have their price, so you will use them only if you know you can profit with their use,   e.g. because *business keys*   can be changed, reused etc.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber assuming we are talking about Kimball dimensional modelling then I'd have to disagree with both your points. Point 1 I would argue makes little difference in performance - the surrogate key on  Date Dim could be 20210105, "20210105" or 05/01/2021 or 10001 and it will make no measurable difference. Point 2 I fundamentally disagree with: the surrogate key should be integers assigned in sequence (apart from a few special cases where there are other options e.g. the Date Dim) - if you don't understand why then this you've missed one of the key points of the Kimball methodology.

Comment: @NickW I do not argue against *methodology*, I'm speaking about my experiences...

Comment: My idea is to model a third dimension with the attributes of location in that new dimension. But I don't find references about a dimension with a PK with multiples columns. 

About surrogate keys,  the source system already generates that for me and I don't enforce referential integrity in physical layer for parallelism.

Answer (score 0):

my thoughts...

1. Having a 3rd dimension for location is definitely a viable option. You could also include store details within this Dim (but still have the location as its level of granularity) and have a Location > Store hierarchy
2. You won't find references to a dimension having a PK with multiple columns because that would break one of the fundamental design principles of dimensional modelling
3. I'm confused/surprised by your statement that your source system is generating surrogate keys? Given that surrogate keys (in this context) are entirely an artefact within a data warehouse, it seems unlikely that a source system would be generating them

Answer (score 0):

Be careful another dimension = more joins = complex queries.

You can stick to a simple modeling :
[image]